# Writing to a file after parsing

Tags: python, file-writing

I have written a small python code where it will read a sample csv file and copy its first column to a temp csv file. Now when I try to compare that temporary file with another text file and try to write result to another file called result file, The file is created but with empty content.

But when i tested it in chunks, It is working fine

```
import csv
f = open("sample.csv", "r")
reader = csv.reader(f)

data = open("temp1.csv", "w")
w = csv.writer(data)
for row in reader:
    my_row = []
    my_row.append(row[0])
    w.writerow(my_row)

with open('temp1.csv', 'r') as file1:
    with open('serialNumber.txt', 'r') as file2:
        same = set(file1).intersection(file2)

with open('result.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    for line in same:
        file_out.write(line)
        print line
```

sample.csv

> M11435TDS144,STB#1,Router#1
>
> M11543TH4292,STB#2,Router#1
>
> M11509TD9937,STB#3,Router#1
>
> M11543TH4258,STB#4,Router#1

serialNumber.txt

> G1A114042400571
>
> M11543TH4258
>
> M11251TH1230
>
> M11435TDS144
>
> M11543TH4292
>
> M11509TD9937

Comment: is it possible that `same` might be empty?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. can u please say what do u mean by, same might be empty?

Comment: Given your code, does the last line `print line` actually print something or not? What @ozgur is asking whether the `intersection` between `file1` and `file2` might be empty.

Comment: It is not printing any thing..But when I am executing last eight lines alone, it is printing

Answer (score 0):

You should close the output file (`temp1.csv`) before you can read data from it.

```
import csv
f = open("sample.csv", "r")
reader = csv.reader(f)

data = open("temp1.csv", "w")
w = csv.writer(data)
for row in reader:
    my_row = []
    my_row.append(row[0])
    w.writerow(my_row)
data.close()  # <--- Should close it before reading it in the same program !!

with open('temp1.csv', 'r') as file1:
    with open('serialNumber.txt', 'r') as file2:
        same = set(file1).intersection(file2)

with open('result.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    for line in same:
        file_out.write(line)
        print line
```

Comment: Thank you Enix...But it is still the same problem..when i execute it nothing is being written to  result file even after closing the file. Is the logic for taking out the first column from sample.csv and copying it in temp1.csv not correct?

Comment: how about just executing the first few lines of code until line `data.close()`?do you get the correct result in `temp1.csv`?

Comment: Yes Enix..a temp1.csv is created with data in it

Answer (score 0):

**Points regarding code**:

- `data` file handle is not closed. `data.close()` after writing to `temp1.csv`.
- In your code, `same = set(file1).intersection(file2)`, you are directly passing file handle `file2` to intersection. It expects list. This is exact problem is. It should be `same = set(file1.readlines()).intersection(file2.readlines())`

**Working Code:**

```
import csv
f = open("sample.csv", "r")
reader = csv.reader(f)

data = open("temp1.csv", "wb")
w = csv.writer(data)

for row in reader:
    my_row = []
    if len(row) != 0:
      my_row.append(row[0])
      w.writerow(my_row)
#File should be closed
data.close()

with open('temp1.csv', 'r') as file1:
    with open('serialNumber.txt', 'r') as file2:
      tmp_list = (file1.readlines())
      ser_list = (file2.readlines())
      same = set(file1.readlines()).intersection(file2.readlines())


with open('result.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    for line in same:
        file_out.write(line)
```

**Content of temp1.csv:**

```
M11435TDS144
M11543TH4292
M11509TD9937
M11543TH4258
```

**Content of result.txt :**

```
M11543TH4258
M11543TH4292
M11435TDS144
```

*You can use `with` for opening files **sample.csv** and **temp1.csv** as below.*

```
import csv

with open("sample.csv") as f:
  with open("temp1.csv",'wb') as data:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    w = csv.writer(data)
    for row in reader:
      my_row = []
      my_row.append(row[0])
      w.writerow(my_row)


with open('temp1.csv', 'r') as file1:
    with open('serialNumber.txt', 'r') as file2:
      same = set(file1.readlines()).intersection(file2.readlines())

with open('result.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    for line in same:
        file_out.write(line)
```

Comment: Hii Dinesh.. Thank you for the reply. My result file is still not showing any data

Comment: Can you please add print (same) after same = set(list(file1)).intersection(list(file2)) and give me the output?

Comment: The output is : set([])

Comment: Can you please share data of sample.csv and serialNumber.txt ?

Comment: Included in the post

Comment: Also what i have noticed is if I am creating that temp1 file externally, it is working good. May be is it like the program generated temp1.csv cannot be read?